# How do I set-up a remote Web server URL in the xmlPath on a JSP file?

Tags: xml, jsp, url-routing, weblogic-10.x

The index.jsp file I'm working on currently references XML content that is deployed in the same open directory in WebLogic, but now I'm trying to separate code from content and need to host the XMLs on a separate server for someone else to update.

The code in the JSP currently provides a relative path to the XML content:

```
<ssm:getDom var="cm" xmlPath="/content/{lg}/{ct}/about/pagecopy/version-3/common.xml"/>
```

Where my tag processor would then take the cm variable and the file in the given path to instantiate a DOM ojbect.

Conceivably, the only required update would be:

```
<ssm:getDom var="cm" xmlPath="http://web-server-url.com/content/{lg}/{ct}/about/pagecopy/version-3/common.xml"/>
```

I already tested the Web servers URLs in my browser and the files are reachable, but the error I'm getting upon re-deployment is:

ServletException:  org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: $:dom
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil$JstlVariableContext.notNull    (XPathUtil.java:160)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.XPathUtil$JstlVariableContext.getVariableValue(XPathUtil.java:100)

and the content is not displaying - it displays fine again if I put the /content folder back in my main deployment package.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a virtual directory mapping and it didn't work because the JSPs don't directly render the XMLs and require a transformer to do that work instead; I found the transformer we were using,  updated the xmlPath prefix and it worked.